# How to check if alias is not replacing an actual command?

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

How can I know if an alias I make (in `.bash_aliases`) is not replacing an actual command by same name? I don't want to do such things by accident.

(I looked in "Questions that may already have your answer" and "Similar Questions" but did not see matches)

I'm asking because I feel there is no warning given by the system (Ubuntu 13.10).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `type` in terminal for this.

Say you have a command `rm` as alias `rm -i`. If you check,

```
type rm
```

you will get,

```
rm is aliased to `rm -i'
```

If you do not have any alias for `rm` you will get,

```
rm is /bin/rm
```

Comment: This doesn't help with commands like `locate` which seems to me to be an alias for a more powerful `find` command, but I could be wrong. I'm actually on a quest to find the difference

Comment: @MishaP `type locate` returns "locate is `/usr/bin/locate`". See [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/locate.findutils.1.html) of `locate` for more. I did not understood why you think it an alias.

Comment: you're right, it's not. I'm used to using `find`, so when I saw someone using `locate` I just assumed it was some system default alias like `ll`. When I have a little extra time I'll dig in to try to find the difference. Hopefully it's not just (essentially) duplicate commands. That would really suck....

Answer (score 3):

**Warning**: this method requires you to actually run the command, unlike the other answers that "report" on the shell state. You can never be sure till execution-time, can you?

In your shell, type

```
set -x
```

You will see `+ ...` lines as the shell executes. For example, when I run `ls`, which is usually aliased to `ls --color=auto` on Ubuntu, I get this:

```
$ ls ~
+ ls --color=auto /home/rctay
bin         ext    foo.py      Music     shared     tmp-www                tmux-client-32280.log
...
```

To turn it off, run `set +x`.

Answer (score 1):

Before defining the alias for some command, call it `fn`, run `type` on the command name:

```
type fn
```

If there is no command of that name, `type` will return `not found`.

After you have defined an alias, you can use `locate` to check for possible conflicts:

```
locate '*bin/fn'
```

This looks anywhere on the system for a command named `fn` in a directory whose name would indicate that it is an executable.  Note that this is not the same as `type` because `locate` will look in `bin` directories that may not be on your default path.